# Could somebody please tell what tree genus is this?

Tags: species-identification, botany

Leaves of a tree in south Asia:[image: leaves of a tree in south Asia]
It is in Pakistan, found in flat land habitats.

Comment: South asia is a bit vague. Can you be a bit more precise and what kind of habitat you found it?

Comment: Please provide approximate size of leaves. also, if possible, providing additional images/descriptions of the plant is always helpful: closeups of leaves, images of flowers, plant growth size and habit, etc.